# SAP VL02N 'Copy Pack Quantities As Dlv. Quantities' FM

Tags: abap, function-module, sap-erp

Any idea how I could copy/achieve a VL02N functionality 'Copy Pack Quantities As Dlv. Quantities'? Is there any FM or BAPI that we could use?

Thanks for any help.

[image]

Comment: I definitely have tried to find this in the past and ended up having to write a BDC.  However, that was nearly 10 years ago. Something may have been released since.

Comment: Hi @BryanCain yes. Currently, I used BDC. I am still in search for FM :)